# How do I properly set Up ListItem level permissions?

Tags: development, permissions, tasks, task-list, task-assignment

For the sake of simplicity (and reproducability for future searches) I am going to exclude the steps I have done already.

I am building a Web with Workflows and Workflow Tasks.

I want all users to see all Tasks, but only the assigned user to edit the Task (Approve/Deny it).

How do I manage this? The Web itself is deployed via a Feature, so C# would be great and EventReceivers are an option. But other ways are also appreciated.